# How to make taxes work in business central api?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, dynamics-business-central

I don't understand how to make functioning tax areas with the Microsoft Dynamics Business Central API. I can create tax areas and associate them with customers, but they have no affect on sales order line items. Even though they will appear with the actual order line item. I think the reason is they don't have any associated tax jurisdiction entities. Because when one makes a tax area in the actual Business Central GUI, the tool demands that you also add at least one tax jurisdiction to said tax area for it to function. But I can't associate (or I don't understand how) a tax jurisdiction with a tax area with the API. But before I even talk about associating a tax jurisdiction I have to figure out how to create a tax jurisdiction. Does anyone know how to get the taxes to work with the API for Business Central? Any pointers? It seems to me I have to enter specific tax areas because there is no way of directly inputing the tax amounts/percentages using the API, tax amounts are read only. I haven't been able to find a whole lot on this otherwise I wouldn't ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the only thing you can do is expose the Tax Jurisdictions by creating a custom API. Which I plan on doing.